# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Tags: android, exception, parameters

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 67:

```
String url = null;
            try {
                url = Utils.BASE_URL + "/v1/video/updateDeepLink?code=" + URLEncoder.encode(qr_code, "UTF-8") + "&CbranchLink=" + URLEncoder.encode(broadcastUrl, "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.e("LOG", "Executed URL==> " + url);
            HttpPost request = null;
            request = new HttpPost(url);
```

Comment: print out the query string and look which character is on index 67

Comment: Also add the complete stacktrace to the question

Comment: post your complete error log